# How can I call a raw address from Rust?

Tags: rust, function-pointers, osdev

I am writing an OS in Rust and need to directly call into a virtual address that I'm calculating (of type `u32`). I expected this to be relatively simple:

```
let code = virtual_address as (extern "C" fn ());
(code)();
```

However, this complains that the cast is non-primitive. It suggests I use the `From` trait, but I don't see how this could help (although I am relatively new to Rust and so could be missing something).

```
error[E0605]: non-primitive cast: `u32` as `extern "C" fn()`
 --> src/main.rs:3:16
  |
3 |     let code = virtual_address as (extern "C" fn ());
  |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: an `as` expression can only be used to convert between primitive types. Consider using the `From` trait
```

I have everything in `libcore` at my disposal, but haven't ported `std` and so can't rely on anything that isn't no_std

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Casts of the type `_ as f-ptr` are not allowed (see [the Rustonomicon chapter on casts](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/casts.html)). So, as far as I can tell, the only way to cast to function pointer types is to use the all mighty weapon [`mem::transmute()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/mem/fn.transmute.html).

But before we can use `transmute()`, we have to bring our input into the right memory layout. We do this by casting to `*const ()` (a void pointer). Afterwards we can use `transmute()` to get what we want:

```
let ptr = virtual_address as *const ();
let code: extern "C" fn() = unsafe { std::mem::transmute(ptr) };
(code)();
```

If you find yourself doing this frequently, various kinds of macros can remove the boilerplate. One possibility:

```rust
macro_rules! example {
    ($address:expr, $t:ty) => {
        std::mem::transmute::<*const (), $t>($address as _)
    };
}
```

```rust
let f = unsafe { example!(virtual_address, extern "C" fn()) };
f();
```

---

However, a few notes on this:

- If you, future reader, want to use this to do simple FFI things: please take a moment to think about it again. Calculating function pointers yourself is rarely necessary.
- Usually `extern "C"` functions have the type `unsafe extern "C" fn()`. This means that those functions are unsafe to call. You should probably add the `unsafe` to your function.

Comment: Please note that I'm absolutely not an expert on unsafe-things! If someone knows better, please let me know; then I can edit or delete my answer!

Comment: Rust doesn't do anything fancy here. `fn()` is a plain function pointer. As long as there's a function at `virtual_address`, calling conventions and signatures match, it's OK to do the cast and call the function.

Comment: Awesome, I'll need to do some more setup to see if this actually works, but it does compile! Thanks very much @LukasKalbertodt.

Comment: @red75prime The code itself isn't fancy, but does rely on being passed a valid virtual address in my case (with numerous things to think about: physical -> virtual calculation, actually mapping the code etc.) so I think it does fit as an `unsafe fn` in Rust's paranoia (in a good sense of the word)

Comment: can we tell Rust which calling convention such an inline-casted function has?