# How to dereference C/C++ void * to struct or callback in Rust?

Tags: c++, rust, ffi

I want to write an AI for an old game, in Rust. AI's for this game are libraries, in its Linux port it's just an `.so` file exporting:

```c
extern "C" void client(int Command, int Player, void *Data);
```

`void *Data` can be either struct (depends on `Command`) or this function:

```c
typedef int TServerCall(int Command, int Player, int Subject, void *Data);
```

In C++, AI code casts it depending on command, to a struct of known size or callback, like:

```c
typedef int __stdcall TServerCall(int Command, int Player, int Subject, void *Data);
```

or to struct:

```c
// where G is a extern TNewGameData G;

G = *(TNewGameData *) Data;
```

And then I can access fields of `G` or other structs, or arrays.

Question:

How do I cast data in form of `void *` to struct or function in Rust?

Comment: Related question: [Call a raw address from Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46134477/call-a-raw-address-from-rust)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can cast raw pointers in Rust.

```
use libc::{c_void, c_int};

#[repr(C)]
struct TNewGameData {
    // the fields go here
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn client(command: c_int, player: c_int, data: *mut c_void) {
    // Cast raw pointer to the right type.
    let game_data_ptr = data as *mut TNewGameData;
    // Convert to Rust reference.
    let game_data = unsafe { &mut *data };
}
```

Comment: Can I cast it to a function somehow using this approach?